# Prevent SQL injection in queries with exec or execute

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-injection

I'm developing a reporting web with Visual Studio 2017. All my **SQL queries are parameterized and works properly**. The problem is in some queries that have exec command like in a procedure.

For example:

Instead of `SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE id=@id`
I've put `exec('SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE id=@id')`

The **exec** case doesn't work. The error message is:

> Must declare the scalar variable ""@id""." & vbCrLf & "Must declare the scalar variable ""@id""."
>   Anyone knows a possible solution?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Either use `sp_executesql` or turn the queries into functions/stored procedures and call them using parameters.

Comment: Another option is to use EF and construct the queries using LINQ. This will even allow you to construct the actual query based the user's choices, eg use different `Where()` conditions, `OrderBy()` fields

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Provided you're using parameters in "parameterizable" locations (i.e. you're not trying to parameterize table/column names), you can use [`sp_executesql`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql) to keep using parameters:

```
exec sp_executesql N'select * from tabla where id=@id',N'@id int',@id = @id
```

Using `exec` creates a new context which doesn't have access to any of the outer variables/parameters, but `sp_executesql` lets you explicitly pass variables into the inner context. (There's no requirement that the inner and outer variable names are the same, but it's often simplest to keep it so)